# can gcc do loop optimizations (strip-mining/blocking) on unknown iteration count?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to make use of the graphite loop optimization framework available in GCC >= 4.4, but I can't seem to get it to apply any transformations if the iteration count is unknown.
E.g. this example code:

```
int __attribute__((hot)) 
f(double * restrict a, double *restrict b, double *restrict c,  const int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       c[i] = a[i] + b[i*2];
    }
}
```

if compiled gcc 4.7 (graphite/cloog enabled):

```
gcc -floop-strip-mine  -O2 -c -std=c99 file.c
```

no strip mining is done.

But if I make the iteration count constant (e.g. 100), it will do the strip mining as advertised.

I tried giving it hints that the iteration count is high (assert( n > 1000), __builtin_expect(n, 1000)) but that does not help.
Brief experiments using profile information did not help either.

So my question is, can gcc do strip mining on unknown iteration counts at all?

Comment: I now tried it with gcc-4.8 and it works as expected, probably just gcc-4.7 does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely read the [GCC 4.5.0 Optimize Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) docs. (Search for `-floop-strip-mine`, about 1/3 of the way down the page)

Also, make sure GCC's getting the `--with-ppl` and `--with-cloog` options (as noted in the docs about using Graphite in `-floop-strip-mine`). Without those, GCC probably won't even try to perform strip mining on your code.

Based on the behavior description and pseudocode examples in the docs, which show some pseudocode loops with finite strip lengths and iteration counts, I'd say that GCC probably does not do strip mining on unknown iteration counts.

From the docs:

Pseudocode original loop:

```
DO I = 1, N
  A(I) = A(I) + C
ENDDO
```

Pseudocode strip-mined loop:

```
DO II = 1, N, 51
  DO I = II, min (II + 50, N)
    A(I) = A(I) + C
  ENDDO
ENDDO
```